# Add all files in a directory using jGit

Tags: java, jgit

I would like to add all the files from a specified directory using  `addFilepattern` to the git repository and commit the change after that. I am expecting to see the files in the commit when I do  `git show` but instead the commits exists but are empty.

This is the code:

```
//create target directory for jGit
        File targetDirectory = new File("/Users/asusti/jGit/");
        if (!targetDirectory.exists()) {
            if (targetDirectory.mkdir()) {
                System.out.println("jGit directory is created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("jGit Directory exists!");
            }
        }

        //create a new Git repository instance
        // The Git-object has a static method to initialize a new repository
        try (Git git = Git.init()
                .setDirectory(targetDirectory)
                .call()) {
            System.out.println("Created a new repository at " + git.getRepository().getDirectory());
            git.add().addFilepattern("/Users/asusti/Downloads").call();
            git.commit().setMessage("Added yaml files to the repository.").setAuthor("anas", "anas@email.com")
            .call();
        } catch (IllegalStateException | GitAPIException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it

```
git.add().addFilepattern(".").call();
CommitCommand commit = git.commit();
commit.setMessage("Added yaml files to the repository.").call();
git.push().call();
```

Comment: From what I understand `addFilepattern(".")` will add all files from the current working directory but my files are from a different directory.

Comment: You can add only files in the current repository. addFilepattern (".") means to add all the modified files in the repository.

Comment: Thank you. I missed the most obvious  ;)